# Android listview - on long click shows wrong contextmenu

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contextmenu

I have two listviews, bookmarklistview and historylistview, one on 
top of another. Bookmarklistview is hidden when historylistview 
is shown and vice-versa. And for long click event, am creating a 
contextmenu. The long click event works fine with historylistview.

Now problem shows up when I long click an item in bookmarklistview, 
the historylistview context menu is shown instead of bookmarklistview
context menu.

How can this happen? Any idea?

Below is the code for bookmarklistview contextmenu

```
public void onCreateContextMenuBookmark(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Delete Bookmark?");
    menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Delete");
    menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Cancel");
}

public boolean onContextItemSelectedBookmark(MenuItem item){
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    if(item.getTitle() == "Delete"){
    //  delete item
    }else if(item.getTitle() == "Cancel"){
    }
    return false;
}
```

Below is the code for historylistview contextmenu

```
public void onCreateContextMenuHistory(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Delete History?");
    menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Delete");
    menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Cancel");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    if(item.getTitle() == "Delete"){
        //     delete item
    }else if(item.getTitle() == "Cancel"){
    }
    return false;
}
```

Ok, I figured out that I can have a single context menu for both the views, something like this

```
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)  
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.history_listView:
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Delete History?");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Cancel");
        break;

    case R.id.bookmark_listView:
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Delete Bookmark?");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Cancel");
    }
}
```

But how do I call two different onContextItemSelected() methods one for each view?

Comment: There should be `item.getTitle().equals("Delete")` instead of `item.getTitle() == "Delete"`

Comment: are you displaying only one listview at a time. If so then for hiding purpose you should use View.GONE instead of View.INVISIBLE

Comment: @ChintanRathod But the same code works fine with historylistview.

Comment: @BharatSharma Well I was using View.INVISIBLE but changing it to View.GONE did help either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this method

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    if(v.getId() == R.id.cover){

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Change Cover");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Take Photo");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Choose From Library");
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.Profilepic){

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Change Profile");
    menu.add(1, v.getId(), 0, "Take Photo");
    menu.add(1, v.getId(), 0, "Choose From Library");
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getGroupId() == 0) {

        if(item.getTitle()=="Take Photo"){ showCoverCameraFragment(); }
        else if(item.getTitle()=="Choose From Library"){showCoverLibraryFragment();}
        else {return false;}

    } else if (item.getGroupId() == 1) {

        if(item.getTitle()=="Take Photo"){showProfileCameraFragment();}
        else if(item.getTitle()=="Choose From Library"){showProfileLibraryFragment();}
        else {return false;}
    }




    return true;
}
```